# Ajuda com flexbox

Tags: html5, css3

Estou com dificuldades para fazer isso com flexbox. Com float foi muito fácil, pois ele organiza facilmente.

```css
.slider > div > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider > div.item-1 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
}

.slider > div.item-2 {
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

.slider > div.item-3 {
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="item-1">
        <img src="https://www.dominios.pt/wp-content/uploads/domain-site.png" alt="Img 1">
    </div>
    <div class="item-2">
        <img src="https://www.dominios.pt/wp-content/uploads/domain-site.png" alt="Img 1">
    </div>
    <div class="item-3">
        <img src="https://www.dominios.pt/wp-content/uploads/domain-site.png" alt="Img 1">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Jovem fiz uma resposta 100% com flex-box e com detalhes para vc entender melhor como foi feito. Repare que agora não tem problema pra vc usar `order` caso queira, pois eu mantive seu HTML intácto só mexi no CSS e todas as `div` continuam irmãs agora.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou deixar uma opção sem precisar encapsular as imagens da direita em um `div` nova. Desse forma vc pode continuar usando o seletor direto `>` e todas as `divs` com imagem estão no mesmo nível.

Então nessa opção todas as imagens são irmão, e vc pode usar a propriedade `order` do `flex` livremente para reorganizar os irmão caso queira. Só lembre que não é só o `order` que vc precisa mudar, tem outras propriedades que vc precisa mudar quando a imagem 3 por exemplo for para o lugar da imagem 1.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Não mexi em NADA no HTML, todos os ajustes foram no CSS, assim as `div` continuai irmãs diretas etc.

O principal aqui é usar o `flex-column`, assim o "grid" se alinha em colunas, a primeira coluna é ocupada pela imagem maior que tem 60% da largura, e 100% da altura, assim as próximas duas imagens de 40% de largura e 300px / 200px de altura ficam no espaço restante a direita.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider > div > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.slider > .item-1 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 500px;
}
.slider > .item-2,
.slider > .item-3 {
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
}
.slider > .item-3 {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="item-1">
      <img src="https://www.dominios.pt/wp-content/uploads/domain-site.png" alt="Img 1">
  </div>
  <div class="item-2">
      <img src="https://www.dominios.pt/wp-content/uploads/domain-site.png" alt="Img 1">
  </div>
  <div class="item-3">
      <img src="https://www.dominios.pt/wp-content/uploads/domain-site.png" alt="Img 1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Hugo é isso que queria!!

Comment: @IsmaelSIlva legal jovem!! Se ainda ficar com alguma dúvida de algum detalhe é só falar. Abs

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia incluir as divs 2 e 3 em uma outra div contêiner, criando uma segunda coluna. Também é preciso ajustar alguns estilos no CSS, removendo o sinal `>` e alterando a largura das divs 2 e 3 para `100%`, já que elas vão estar em um contêiner com os `40%` de largura:

```css
.slider{
   display: flex;
}

.slider > div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider > div.item-1 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 500px;
}

.slider div.item-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.slider div.item-3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
} 

.slider > div.item2-3 {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="item-1">
        <img src="https://www.dominios.pt/wp-content/uploads/domain-site.png" alt="Img 1">
    </div>
    <div class="item2-3">
       <div class="item-2">
           <img src="https://www.dominios.pt/wp-content/uploads/domain-site.png" alt="Img 1">
       </div>
       <div class="item-3">
           <img src="https://www.dominios.pt/wp-content/uploads/domain-site.png" alt="Img 1">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Entendi, mas queria fazer ele sem o uso de uma div auxiliar, quero usa uma animação no css, para mudar a ordem, mas acho que não vai dar

Comment: Acredito que nada impede de vc alterar a ordem da forma de propus acima. Só acho que com CSS vc não conseguirá alterar a ordem dos elementos. Seria preciso JavaScript.

Comment: Obrigado Sam, pela ajuda!

Comment: Valeu! Qq coisa tmj!